# Control Code behind flow by JavaScript confirm result

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am not sure, whether this is even possible, but I try:

I have an ASP.NET Forms page. There is a FileUpload control. On uploading the file, the file is saved to server and checked, whether it satisfies given criteria (actually, there is some more processing after uploading the file, but I try to keep it simple). If not, a JS confirm should be displayed asking the user "The file does not satisfy given criteria. Do you wish to save the file anyway?". If the user chooses "Yes", file is kept, otherwise it is deleted.

I call the JS confirm like this:

```
Response.Write("<script>confirm('The file does not satisfy given criteria. Do you wish to save the file anyway?');</script>");
```

However, this does not fire the confirm immediately, but after the whole processing is finished and postback is called. Thus, the purpose of the confirm is lost, since after postback the file path is lost and there is no file to keep/delete.

Now, I understand I am mixing here client and server scripts. But, is there a way how to achieve, what I want? I have thought about an option:
uploading & saving the file, path is saved to hidden field -> postback occurs -> confirm prompt is displayed -> result value is stored in hidden field -> another postback -> on load server keeps/deletes the file based on values in hidden fields

However, this seems to be too complicated. Is there a more sophisticated way?

Comment: `The file does not satisfy given criteria` so where does this criteria check happens? On the server side code in the upload function?

Comment: Yes, the whole file processing is a chain of C# methods.

Comment: Are you using any `UpdatePanel` for the page?

Comment: No, haven't heard of it until now... I will take a look at it.

Comment: You can use `RegisterStartupScript` like this to throw an alert to the user from your server code `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "confirm", "return confirm('The file does not satisfy given criteria. Do you wish to save the file anyway?');", true);`

Comment: Can't you return when the criteria is not satisfied?
Do you need to procces it on server and after the confirm in the client you want the server to take the power back?

Comment: @DennisR Your code works fine, but only after postback. Is there no way how to call the JS confirm without postback, during the file processing?

Comment: @MVCDS Well, I could, but that would be the double postback code I have proposed in my question.

Comment: Is a web service considered a postback? You can use them on forms pages.

Comment: You can use AJAX `WebMethods` and trigger from JavaScript. Please note these webmethods are static and you will not be able to access any form elements. If all the upload functionality is independent then have it written inside the webmethod and throw the `confirm` if the criteria is not met.